# why wasn't this javascript/angular code working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function foo() = { .. do stuff and return value };

$scope.newFunction = function(){
   // Set new local variable foo equal to value of foo()
   var foo = foo();
}
```

When I change the local foo variables name it is fine, I am pretty new to Javascript but to me I thought creating a new local variable with the same name would be fine.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a reasonable question

Comment: When describing your code, make sure you avoid using the phrase "it doesn't work" in whatever form. Instead, *describe exactly what happened*

Comment: makes sense but I thought var foo is a new scope and nothing outside will see it, so thats why I was confused.

Comment: @CatznDogz that would be `$scope.foo`.

Comment: You may be confusing the concept of scope in javascript and angular's `$scope` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More information about variable hoisting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

What you're seeing here is the effect of variable hosting(and shadowing) in your newFunction. After the hoisting phase, your could would logically look like this:

```
function foo() {} // foo is part of newFunction's outer scope
$scope.newFunction = function(){
   var foo; // === undefined
   foo = foo(); //<-- foo is undefined, yet is used as a function
}
```

When you declare a variable with the name foo in that scope(the scope created when newFunction() is called), it will shadow the function foo from the outer scope(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)